# How to merge cells into one by category in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, pivot-table

I have a data like this

| Name | Class |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | A |
| Mike | B |
| Dennis | C |
| Dennis | D |
| Dennis | E |
| Dennis | F |
| Dennis | G |
| Allen | A |
| Allen | C |
| Allen | D |
| Allen | E |

And I want to make the data like this

| Name | Class |
| --- | --- |
| Mike | A,B |
| Dennis | C,D,E,F,G |
| Allen | A,C,D,E |

I have tried power query to transpose but its not working since I have duplicated content in 'Name' column.

Is there any way to achieve this in excel without using VBA? Or it can also be done with python pandas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in `pandas`:-

```
import pandas as pd    
df=pd.read_excel('your file name',engine='openpyxl')
```

then:-

```
newdf=df.groupby('Name')['Class'].sum()
```

The above code will return `series` so now to convert it into `dataframe`:-

```
newdf=newdf.to_frame()
```

Now we create/define a Function:-

```
def func(val):
    return ','.join(val)
```

Now finally we use `apply()` method:-

```
newdf['Class']=newdf['Class'].apply(func)
```

Now if you print `newdf` you will get your desired output

**Output:-**

```
        Class
Name    
Allen   A,C,D,E
Dennis  C,D,E,F,G
Mike    A,B
```

Now save that in an `excel` file by:-

```
newdf.to_excel('file name.xlsx')
```